# (Server) cache problems with jquerymobile site

Tags: caching, jquery-mobile

I've got a problem with too much caching on my first jquerymobile site (http://backpocketgrower.com/).  I upload new versions of pages but only old versions are displayed; I can physically remove pages from the server, yet subsequent browser visits display them.  I've used totally "virgin" machines/browsers on the site and still get old versions of the pages displayed.  I've deleted cache/history from all my browsers (FF, Chrome, Dolphin, Opera, Safari), have added querystrings to the a-tag links to new pages - yet continue to only get old versions of pages presented.

Any ideas of where next I should start looking for a solution?

Thanks/Bruce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can programatically disable the cache. Check out this [documentation at this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06bh14hk%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

As per the link above you should be able to do something like below

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60));
```

or you can do the below in your page itself

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="60" VaryByParam="None" %>
```

From [another link you I learned](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/reference/article.php/3472881/So-You-Dont-Want-To-Cache-Huh.htm) that you can do as below

```
// Stop Caching in IE
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache);

// Stop Caching in Firefox
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Hope this will give you a head start.

Comment: Thanks - I was so focussed on JQM that I didn't think about asp's caching issues.  Cheers/Bruce